# How to sync files' timestamps only?

Tags: rsync

Is there any way to r(?)sync in a Linux command line a timestamps **only** for files which have equal contents **only**?

I.e. some directory structure was copied without coping of a timestamps and then modified independently. Now there is need to copy a timestamps of equal files only to simplify further synchronization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like answer on my question is (almost):

```
rsync -a -c --existing /source/ /destination/
```

This will copy files which are different and as far as I understood silently synchronize timestamps of an equal files.

As usual firstly try it with `-n` (or `--dry-run`) key.

**ADDED:**

There is need to do what was mentioned in my question sometimes. So there is the script which does exactly what I asked for:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Ensure that there is a trailing '/'.
SRC="$(dirname $1)/$(basename $1)/"
DST="$(dirname $2)/$(basename $2)/"

if ! [[ -d "$SRC" ]] || ! [[ -d "$DST" ]]; then
  echo "Usage:"
  echo "  $(basename $0) src/dir dst/dir"
  exit 1
fi

diff -rqs "$SRC" "$DST" | grep -Po "(?<=^Files $SRC).*(?= and $DST.* are identical$)" | rsync -tv --files-from=- "$SRC" "$DST"
```

Answer (score 4):

**For a quicker way of setting the timestamps, I used this instead:**

```
rsync -vrtpi --size-only /media/myname/Dropbox/ /home/myname/Dropbox
```

Where the `-t` option is crucial as it preserves the time stamps and `--size-only` only compares files on size.

Note the trailing backslash '/' after the first Dropbox.

The `-c,` or `--checksum` option may take time.

Before you run, please **dry-run** to see which files are affected:

```
rsync -vrtpi --size-only --dry-run /media/myname/Dropbox/ /home/myname/Dropbox > foo.txt
```

Comment: This may have issues with nanoseconds, where only the second part is copied.